# How to convert UTC timezone to user-defined Timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I need to convert

```
Thu Dec 1 01:09:02 2016 UTC
```

to user time zone

```
Thu Dec 1 01:09:02 2016 IST
```

in PHP without using `DateTime` object.

How do I do that?

Comment: why *without* using DateTime? it's *made* for stuff like this. is this homework you want us to do for you? anyway, what have you *tried yourself* so far?

Answer (score 0):

PHP's DateTime object is pretty flexible.

```
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$date = new DateTime( "2011-01-01 15:00:00", $UTC );
$date->setTimezone( $newTZ );
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: except OP said "without using DateTime". so since this *is* the logical way to go, it is *not* an answer to the question provided.

Comment: @Sudha telling us *why* you don't want to use DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

You can always change your default timezone to user's timezone using location:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```